# Java compilation issue on Linux, using Windows specific

Tags: java, linux, windows, compilation, cross-platform

I encountered a compilation issue under Linux. 
I'm compiling java programs on Linux; the target use is both Linux and Windows.
The code check if in there are platform specific classes (as shown in the code below).
So if the code is running under Linux, the specific Windows code will not be executed.

The issue arise on the use of a platform specific class **Win32MediaTray**

The compile error reported is

```
PrinterScanner.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import sun.print.Win32MediaTray;
                 ^
```

Is it possible to compile it under Linux? Or is it just *impossible*?
I can use some workaround (reflection?)
Needless to say that the compilation under Windows gives no errors.

Thankyou for your help.

For reference, the code behind this issue is the following:

```
 private String getTrayName(Media media) {

    String result = "id:" + media.getValue();
    boolean isWin32 = media.getClass().getName().equals("sun.print.Win32MediaTray");
    if (isWin32) {
        Win32MediaTray w32 = (Win32MediaTray) media;
        result = result + ",winId:" + w32.winID;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Tell us what your error is.  I can guess, but don't want to waste my time.

Comment: Even if you can get it to compile, how would you expect it to run? It's a Windows-specific API...

Comment: @rcook  *"don't want to waste my time"*  Good one.  I've seen a slew of questions recently reduced to 'noise' by people trying to guess answers.

Comment: @JonSkeet  On the basis that 'information is better than speculation', I'd like to hear the answer to that as well.  OTOH (my speculation), it *could* be that the OP is coding an app. that uses different behavior on different platforms (e.g. 'If Windows, put it in the media tray..').

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I hope now the question is a better question

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the class you are trying to use is `sun.print.Win32MediaTray`.

And the answer is that you cannot use it ... or compile a class that uses it ... on a Linux release of Java.  That class is not included in the `rt.jar` file on a Linux release of Java.

Furthermore, you *shouldn't* be using it.  The Java documentation makes it very clear that application code should not make use of classes in the `sun.*` package hierarchy.

---

If you have no choice but to do this, then your best bet is to use reflection to fetch the value of that `w32Id` field.  You'll also need to deal with the case where the `media` object is not an instance of the `Win32MediaTray` class. Beware that you are relying on implementation details that Oracle says specifically that you shouldn't.  There is a risk that they will change (without notice!) in some future Windows release.

The other alternatives are:

- Implement your own platform adapter classes with a different one for each platform.  These have to be compiled separately on each platform, and then dynamically loaded.
- Implement separate codebases for each platform.

Comment: I know I shouldn't be using this package. Right now this code is the only working code (after an extend research) to successfully programmatically select a printer tray for a print job. Please, if you are aware of a better way to achieve this, without using sun.*, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

To make the compiler happy you could implement a dummy class named `sun.print.Win32MediaTray` and make it available both on the compile and runtime classpath. The class doesn't need to work, it only has to be API compatible (same signatures and return types, but in this case you only really need to extend `Media` and have a `public` `int` `winID`), so that you can satisfy both the compiler and the verifier.

At runtime, the version included in `rt.jar` should be loaded on Windows thanks to loading delegation. On Linux, the dummy version is the only one available, but you stated that the program checks for the platform and executes another branch of code, so it shouldn't cause your program to fail.

For example, with the following class on the classpath:

```
package sun.print;

import javax.print.attribute.standard.Media;

public class Win32MediaTray extends Media {
  public int winID = 0xBADC0DE;
  protected Win32MediaTray(int value) {
    super(value);
  }
  static {
    System.out.println("Won't see me on Windows");
  }
}
```

I managed to run this program on Windows:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    for  (PrintService svc : services ) {
      DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE;
      Object o = svc.getSupportedAttributeValues(Media.class, flavor, null);
      if (o != null && o.getClass().isArray()) {
        for (Media media : (Media[]) o) {
          if ( media instanceof Win32MediaTray )
            System.out.println( ((Win32MediaTray) media).winID );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The message in the static initializer is not printed on Windows, because the definition that is actually loaded is the one from `rt.jar`. Obviously, the code can be compiled on any platform.

Comment: Interesting idea, how to craft such class? At last I did it with reflection

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the code that uses windows-specific stuff into a separate jar; then you can compile and include that jar on windows, and leave it off systems otherwise.

One standard way to do this is to have one or more interfaces used by your application code; you can have a factory provide the implementing classes or inject them with Spring or whatever.  But I think rather than "how can I compile this on Linux" your question should be "I have this Windows dependency in an app targeted at multiple operating systems, how do I handle it?"

Comment: Adding another jar/interface/implementation would be a too heavy solution. I'd go for the reflection way.

Comment: Just how is this a "heavier" solution than using reflection?

Comment: It is heavier because I need to fork the build chain between Linux and Windows. Add a new jar/project. Use it from another jar/project. Detect when to use the jar

Comment: Well, of course you decide for yourself what the easier/better solution is.  Whether this solution really is easier depends on just what you have to do with reflection, and we don't know that from this question, don't need to.  But if you're taking on java reflection (or ANY major technology) because your build tool makes an easier solution more difficult, then you should consider whether you have the right build tool.